# Adding footer with a file name, before printing and without deleting existing footer/s

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to create a macro in Word 2010, that will add a footer with the file name, without the extension.

I found a code that displays the file name without the extension when you use a docvariable field:

```
Sub autofilenamefooter()

Dim fname As String
fname = ActiveDocument.Name
fname = Left(fname, InStr(fname, ".") - 1)

With ActiveDocument

   .Variables("fname").Value = fname

   .PrintPreview
   .ClosePrintPreview

End With

End Sub
```

How can I use this to create a macro that:

1. Foots the document with the file name before printing (so that the field will be updated each time you print the document).
2. In addition, the new footer (with the file name) will not delete existing footers, if any. This requirement is due to the fact that the macro should be applied to all documents in our document management system, and some of the documents already have footers (such as firm papers with logos) that I would like to keep.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have doesn't need further code for implementation. Simply place a reference field in the footer in whatever place you want the file name to appear. From the Insert tab select Quick Parts > Fields and insert a DocVariable field. Name the field "Fname" (or any other name matching the name in the code). Then run the code below while the document where you want the file name is active.

```
Sub SetDocVariable()
    ' 28 Dec 2017

    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim Test As String
    Dim VarName As String
    Dim VarValue As String

    VarName = "Fname"
    With ActiveDocument
        Sp = Split(.Name, ".")
        ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1)
        VarValue = Join(Sp, ".")
'        VarValue = ""                  ' Use this line to show nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Test = .Variables(VarName).Value
        If Err Then
            .Variables.Add VarName
            Err.Clear
        End If
        If .Variables(VarName).Value <> VarValue Then .Variables(VarName).Value = VarValue
    End With
End Sub
```

This code will write the file name to the document variable, adding the variable to the document if it didn't exist. The field you inserted will show nothing while the variable is blank. It will show an error if the variable doesn't exist. Set the document variable to "" to have no error and no file name.

A perhaps even better way would be to use one of the built-in document properties (or a custom document property if none of the built-in ones can be diverted for the purpose) in place of the document variable, together with the appropriate reference field (Quick Parts > Document Properties). You would have to type the file name into the property dialog but wouldn't need any code at all.

BTW, the 'FileName' reference field (Quick Parts > Fields > FileName) displays the file name in the format you want but it can't be made to be blank.